# C# client server queue application

Tags: c#

i'm new to client server programming in c#.
i'm currently creating a simple queue application in c# using threading for every client connected.
could someone help me with my code?

the problem with this code is, it only read from one client even tho there are more client connected.

```
       using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;

    namespace Server
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            static TcpListener tcpListener;
            NetworkStream networkStream;
            System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter;
            System.IO.StreamReader streamReader;
            string[,] client = new string[999, 3];
            int connectedclient = 0;
            int queuecount = 0;
            int[] peopleque = new int[999];
            int quenumber = 0;

            public void Listener()
            {
                Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
                string clientip = "";
                if (socketForClient.Connected)
                {
                    AddItem("Client:" + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint + " now connected to server.");
                    client[connectedclient, 0] = socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                    client[connectedclient, 2] = "active";
                    connectedclient++;
                    networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
                    streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(networkStream);
                    streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(networkStream);
                    clientip = socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                    while (true)
                    {
                        string theString = streamReader.ReadLine();

                        if (theString != null && theString != "" && theString != " ")
                        {
                            string Connection = socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                            AddItem("Message received by client (" + Connection + ") : " + theString);
                            if (theString[0] == 'r')
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < connectedclient; i++)
                                {
                                    if (client[i, 0] == socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString())
                                    {
                                        client[i, 1] = theString.Substring(1);
                                        AddItem("Client " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " is connected as kassa " + client[i, 1]);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            if (theString[0] == 'q')
                            {
                                streamWriter.Write(theString);
                                streamWriter.Flush();
                            }

                            switch (theString)
                            {
                                case "exit":
                                    string connectedip = socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < connectedclient; i++)
                                    {
                                        if (client[i, 0] == connectedip)
                                        {
                                            client[i, 0] = "";
                                            client[i, 1] = "";
                                            client[i, 2] = "";
                                            if (connectedclient - 1 != 0)
                                            {
                                                connectedclient--;
                                                client[i, 0] = client[connectedclient, 0];
                                                client[i, 1] = client[connectedclient, 1];
                                                client[i, 2] = client[connectedclient, 2];
                                                client[connectedclient, 0] = "";
                                                client[connectedclient, 1] = "";
                                                client[connectedclient, 2] = "";
                                                break;
                                            }
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    socketForClient.Disconnect(true);
                                    socketForClient.Close();

                                    break;
                                case "break":
                                    connectedip = socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < connectedclient; i++)
                                    {
                                        if (client[i, 0] == connectedip)
                                        {
                                            client[i, 2] = "inactive";
                                            AddItem("client " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " is inactive");
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "empty":
                                    for (int i = 0; i < connectedclient; i++)
                                    {
                                        if (client[i, 0] == socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString())
                                        {
                                            if (queuecount <= 0)
                                            {
                                                client[i, 2] = "empty";
                                                AddItem("Client " + socketForClient.RemoteEndPoint.ToString() + " is empty");
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                streamWriter.WriteLine("q" + peopleque[0] + "t" + client[i, 1]);
                                                peopleque[0] = 0;
                                                for (int j = 0; j < quenumber - 1; j++)
                                                {
                                                    peopleque[j] = peopleque[j + 1];
                                                }
                                                peopleque[queuecount] = 0;
                                                queuecount--;
                                                streamWriter.Flush();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                                case "new":
                                    quenumber++;
                                    bool found = false;
                                    for (int i = 0; i < queuecount; i++)
                                    {
                                        if (client[i, 2] == "empty")
                                        {
                                            streamWriter.Write("q" + quenumber + "t" + client[i, 1]);
                                            streamWriter.Flush();
                                            found = true;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (found == false)
                                    {
                                        peopleque[queuecount] = quenumber;
                                        queuecount++;
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                            if (theString == "exit")
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    streamReader.Close();
                    networkStream.Close();
                    streamWriter.Close();

                }
                AddItem("client " + clientip + " Has Disconnected");
                socketForClient.Close();

            }

            public void StartListening(int NumberOfClient)
            {
                tcpListener.Start();
                for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfClient; i++)
                {
                    Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listener));
                    newThread.Start();
                }
            }

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void AddItem(string item)
            {
                Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    LogListener.Items.Add(item);
                    LogListener.SelectedIndex = LogListener.Items.Count - 1;
                    LogListener.ScrollIntoView(LogListener.Items[LogListener.Items.Count - 1]);
                }));
            }

            private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                //tcpListener = new TcpListener(Convert.ToInt32(PortTxt.Text));
                IPAddress ip = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).Where(address => address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First();
                tcpListener = new TcpListener(ip.MapToIPv4(), Convert.ToInt32(PortTxt.Text)); 
                tcpListener.Start();
                AddItem("************This is Server program************");
                AddItem("This Computer IP Is : " + ip.MapToIPv4().ToString());
                PortTxt.IsEnabled = false;
                StartBtn.IsEnabled = false;
                StartListening(200);
            }

            private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    streamWriter.WriteLine("Fuck");
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                }
                catch
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Exception reading from Server");
                }
            }

            private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < connectedclient; i++)
                {
                    AddItem(client[i, 0]);
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You currently start a set of `Listener` instances on the same port with the same TCP connection. This will not work like you think (as you've noticed). The trick is to have one open Socket and accept clients. When a client is accepted, you spawn a new thread handling the communication. The basic scheme would be:

1. Create `Socket`
2. Call `BeginAcceptSocket`
3. In callback of `BeginAcceptSocket`, spawn a new thread for the client connected
4. Call `BeginAcceptSocket` again to listen for new clients